# Styling react native picker - specifically text alignment (iOS)

Tags: javascript, css, ios, react-native, picker

I have a picker with full screen width and the text is aligned in the center. I want the text to align to the left but having difficulty.

```
formPicker:{
    marginTop:10,
    backgroundColor:'#eee',
    alignSelf:'flex-start',
    //alignContent:'flex-start',
    //justifyContent:'flex-start',
    //textAlign:'left'
}

<Picker style={styles.formPicker} selectedValue={selectedValue} onValueChange={this.pickerValueChanged}>
                    {pickerItems}
                </Picker>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react native picker,label styling in ios is provided itemStyle prop

```
<Picker itemStyle={{textAlign:'left'}} selectedValue={selectedValue} onValueChange={this.pickerValueChanged}>
                    {pickerItems}
                </Picker>
```

for more information check [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#itemstyle)

Comment: 'flex-start' is not valid for textAlign. If you change it to 'left' I shall accept your answer.